# iPython throwing an error when launched: "ipythonrc not found"

Tags: python, macos, ipython

I'm getting a strange error when I launch iPython. I'm running Snow Leopard

```
WARNING: Configuration file ipythonrc not found. Ignoring request.
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/IPython/ConfigLoader.py", line 66, in load
    fname = filefind(fname,incpath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/IPython/genutils.py", line 555, in filefind
    ' not found in current or supplied directories:' + `alt_dirs`
IOError: File'ipythonrc' not found in current or supplied directories:u'/Users/admin_mcadminson/.ipython'

WARNING: Problems loading configuration file 'ipythonrc'
Starting with default -bare bones- configuration.
```

This is the error message that follows:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/IPython/ipmaker.pyc in force_import(modname, force_reload)
     61         reload(sys.modules[modname])
     62     else:
---> 63         __import__(modname)
     64         
     65 

ImportError: No module named ipy_user_conf
WARNING: /Users/admin_mcadminson/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py does not exist, please run %upgrade!
WARNING: Loading of ipy_user_conf failed.
```

Comment: That's not really an error; just a warning. Do you have an `.ipythonrc` configuration file? You may not need one, but if you want to create one it looks like you could place it in `/Users/admin_mcadminson`.

Comment: What version of ipython are you running?

Comment: iPython-2.7, yes this is a warning but it degrades into an error. I've posted the following error message above.

Comment: 2.7 refers to the version of Python that IPython was written with/for, but you have Python 2.6 installed.  IPython version number would be more like 0.12 or 0.13 instead.  In terminal, type `ipython --version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your version of IPython is outdated, as IPython no longer uses `ipythonrc` files for configuration.  You probably should just [upgrade it](http://ipython.org/install.html).

Before you do that, though, you should probably consider upgrading your [python installation](http://www.python.org/download/) to 2.7 as well, since you're using 2.6.

Comment: And as long as you're reconsidering your workflow, look into pythonbrew and virtualenv! Let's shave ALL the yaks!!! :)

Comment: If their username is `admin_mcadminson` presumably they can do a full install :)

Answer (score 0):

The file path was not found, so you could manually create the file with the path `/Users/admin_mcadminson/.ipython/ipythonrc` to get around the check. I would also recommend to update ipython as a long term solution though.